# Create new Notifcation Channels

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I am working in a screen where the user is able to customize the notification (for example: Light color, vibration...) and re-customize anytime the user wants to (so the user is able to turn the light off and on anytime he/she wants to).

So far i did this:

```
private fun createNotification(
    title: String,
    details: String,
    vibration: Boolean,
    light: Boolean,
    lightColor: Int? = null
) {
    val channel = NotificationChannel(
        CHANNEL_ID,
        CHANNEL_NAME,
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    ).apply {
        enableVibration(vibration)
        vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 400, 200, 400, 200, 400)
        enableLights(light)
        setLightColor(lightColor ?: Color.GREEN)

    }
    notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

}
```

But the problem is the `deleteNotificationChannel` function reads as the following:

> If you create a new channel with this same id, the deleted channel will be un-deleted with all of the same settings it had before it was deleted.

How should i approach this situation? Should i store some counter number in the SharedPreferences or what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can concat counter to the channel id, delete the previous one, create with the new one. You can skip `SharedPreferences` though, from the previous id, extract the count and increment it.